# Node JS Asynchronous method call never return | Sequelize querying not working

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, node-modules

In the code below, it never reaches the line after await method call. I am using Sequelize node module for querying database. Sequelize version 6.21.0
Earlier I was using Sequelize v3.22.0, with that version Promise was used and it was working fine. Now I upgraded Sequelize and changed Promise to Async Await call.

```
locale ={};

locale.list=[];

locale.locale = async ()=>{
   locale.list=[];
   const findAllLocale = await global.db.Locale.findAll({
        attributes: {
            exclude: ['createdAt','updatedAt']
        },
        where: null 
    });


    findAllLocale.forEach(function(locale){
        global.locale.list.push(locale);
        
    });
}
locale.locale();
module.exports = locale;
```

Comment: Did you try to add some `console.log` right after `const findAllLocale`?

Comment: Yes, it's not even going to that.

Comment: Try to turn on SQL logging and look at a generated SQL query if any

Comment: Can you please suggest any links for enabling that.

Comment: I have tried with "logging: console.log"  but nothing in console got printed.

Comment: Did the app reach the line `locale.list=[];`?

Comment: Are you sure Sequelize can connect to DB successfully?

Comment: Got the issue, updated pg module to version 8.7.0. Thanks @Anatoly